# MAYAN-EDMS REST API: Documents are not getting checked in

Tags: python, django, dms, mayanedms

**Overview**

I'm try to maintain document versioning in **MAYAN EDMS** using **REST API**. If one user open and updating document then document will be checked out and on completion of changes user will check in document with new version which will be available for other users.

**Problem**

Documents are not getting checked in using REST API. It responds with status code 500 Error: Internal Server Error, without any exception etc.
[Swagger API Call Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIOeX.png)